# How to prevent useEffect to trigger the function multiple times?

Tags: reactjs

Why is this code returning two pieces of data, as though it were calling the function twice? It is logging two different pieces of data in the console.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    
    const getAllPromptsHandler = () => {
        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_MORSE_ENCODE_API}/prompts/getOnePrompt`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setPrompt(data);
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(data)
        })
    };

    getAllPromptsHandler()
}, []);
```

[image]